# Action init not firing after update WP 5.2.2

Tags: wordpress, action, updates, init, visual-composer

I recently updated my website to WP 5.2.2 and 'init' action seems not to fire anymore.. I had few VC element mapped to that action but they are not working anymore..

This is the vc_map init code:

```
class VC_Extensions_FancyBox extends WPBakeryShortCode {

        function __construct() {
            if( has_action('init') ){
                die('has init');  // this is printing correctly
            }
            add_action( 'init', array($this, 'banner_init'));
            add_shortcode('vc_fancybox', array($this, 'vc_fancybox_func'));
        }

        function banner_init() {
            if( has_action('init') ){
                die('has banner_init'); //this is not printing at all..
            }
            vc_map( array(........) );
        }


        function vc_fancybox_func() {
            ....
        }
}
```

I added 2 checks in the code, the first one debugs correctly, the other one doesn't. Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you very much

EDIT: using action 'wp_loaded' the element is showing correctly...

Answer (score 1):

As per Edit, I just replace 'init' to 'wp_loaded' and Worked perfectly

add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'vc_progressbar_mapping' ) );

//add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'vc_progressbar_mapping' ) );

Comment: Hello @Ludo, Nice to see your problem fixed now.